# R Trying to use for() to fill a matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Trouble in R

I'm having trouble filling a matrix with values using a for() loop.
I'm starting with making a blank matrix 1-100

```
z <- matrix(NA, ncol=100, nrow=100)
q <- 1:100
```

I need to fill each nrows with 1-100 
so that the original matrix becomes the sequence 1-100 in every row

i tried

```
for(n in 1:nrows(z)){
    print(q)
}
```

but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought the website was R specific at first

Comment: Thanks for formatting help as well ^^

Answer (score 1):

`print` just prints to the screen without changing your matrix in any way. It would be better to do this without any loop at all.

```
z <- matrix(rep(1:100, each=100), ncol=100, nrow=100)
```

If you *must* use a loop,

```
for(n in 1:nrow(z)){
    z[n,] = q
}
```

Note that it is `nrow`   not `nrows`

Comment: I have to use the for loop as part of an exercise, is there a certain function that lets me insert the sequence into the existing matrix?

Comment: You don't actually need `rep`; if you specify `nrow` and `ncol`, if the vector isn't long enough, it will get recycled, so you can just do `matrix(seq(100), 100, 100, byrow = TRUE)`. Less clear, but shorter: `col(diag(100))`

Comment: @alistaire    That gives the sequence 1:100 down the columns,  not across the rows

Comment: Ohh I understand. So the   'z[n,]' is specifying for each row of z . Thank you!